# starting gpfs having error Unable to verify kernel/module configuration

Tags: kernel

[root@localhost ~]# /usr/lpp/mmfs/bin/mmstartup -a

Fri Nov 15 18:42:06 IST 2019: mmstartup: Starting GPFS ...
localhost:  mmremote: startSubsys: The /lib/modules/3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64/extra/mmfslinux.ko kernel extension does not exist.
Use mmbuildgpl command to create the needed kernel extension for your kernel or copy the binaries from another node with the identical environment.
localhost:  mmremote: startSubsys: Unable to verify kernel/module configuration.
mmstartup: Command failed. Examine previous error messages to determine cause.

Answer (score 1):

**Install dependencies:**

```
yum -y install kernel-devel cpp gcc gcc-c++ kernel-headers
```

**Execute:**

```
mmbuildgpl
```

**Try again:**

```
/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin/mmstartup -a
```

have fun! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yum install following and rebuild gpl.

```
kernel-devel
cpp
gcc
gcc-c++
binutils
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
Seems you have the old kernel module 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64 , please check first the current running kernel, and install kerne-devel with same version.

Please note the following packages are required and dep for mmbuildgpl.

```
cpp
gcc
gcc-c++
kernel-devel
kernel-headers
binutils
elfutils-libelf-devel
gcc-toolset-11-elfutils-libelf-devel
```

Upgrading:

```
libgcc
libgcc
libgomp
libstdc++
libstdc++
```

Installing dependencies:
annobin
glibc-devel
glibc-headers
isl
libmpc
libstdc++-devel
libxcrypt-devel
elfutils-libelf-devel x86_64 0.186-1.el8
gcc-toolset-11-elfutils-libelf-devel x86_64 0.185-5.el8

After these use :/root `# mmbuildgpl`
Then: :/root # `systemctl start gpfs.service`

For me worked. Hope it helps